# Application Time span control Android

Tags: android, datetime, controls

I want to develop an app which user cant open after given days time or will pop up activity that time span is over .
I want to design an app. which user can use for 15 days after that user cant use its functionality.

Comment: Not possible... you should make demo version and full version of application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - how to make trial version of android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098409/android-how-to-make-trial-version-of-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

For “normal” software a solution is to read the install date and add the time span. Then check on every start or resume the date. If the time is over show a dialog and finish app.

I know this is not really save solution if the customer knows it, so please don’t discuss about this.  But is maybe a better solution than building two apps?

Comment: I don't think this is better solution than making two apps. Lets assume your app having some functionality which you want to provide into your paid app but in demo for 15 days. What happens when user changes the device date before launching your app. isn't it be possible that the user can use trial version app even after 15 days.  And the funny case is that what happen when user clears application data?

Comment: As I already mentioned, it’s a solution which can adapted to android and a new idea instead of building two apps. You need to get the date from an independent source, like a website or something. You need also to save the date a secure place. If you think the user will screw you up you need to deactivate you app for security reasons.